# How to insert data into Azure Cosmos DB using Azure Logic apps?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I would like to store the outcome of a logic app (success/failure) into a table in Cosmos DB for reporting purposes using logic app.

I would like to know;

1. How do I create Azure Cosmos DB and a table to store success/failure messages as the last step of the same logic app ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you pre create and connect to cosmosdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few workarounds that we can give it a try

**WAY-1:**

- In this way, we must need to have a particular parameter that defines the whole logic app success or failure of the condition so that we can use the `condition` connector.

  > **(NOTE:** Here we need to keep in mind that when a connector fails the flow stops till there itself and so we are using this method **)**
- Set the required variable to success/failure.
- creating own format using `compose` connector.
- Sending the compose outputs to our table in cosmos DB.

Below are the screenshots for your reference
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the output :

[image]
[image]

---

**WAY-2**
Create nested logic apps

**(NOTE:** Even in this case we must remember that if one connector in one logic app fails it won't reach the next logic app **)**

Comment: thank you. This gave me an insight how to proceed.